# How do I redirect user customer to the page he/she was before a log in success?

Tags: redirect-url

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1

Only logged in customer can access a couple of pages of my website. 
So, when a non-logged in customer tries to access a page that needs him/her to be logged in,  he/she is redirected to the login page. Using the following code.

```
if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
{
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
}
```

After login success the customer is redirected to his/her account panel (the previous page location is lost).

Is there any way to make magento go back to the page where the customer was, after login succes ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to the page of the customer must login :
Mage::getModel('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl([the link of your page])

Comment: It's not redirecting to the privious page, even by using your code snippet...

Answer (score 1):

Go to *System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Login Options* and set the value for `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` to `No`.

Comment: Login Options is already set to no.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two options to control the redirect target after customer log in:

1. Set the `after_auth_url` property at the customer session.
2. In combination with the aforementioned [suggestion by Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/59781), add a `referer` request parameter to the loginPost request.

See [`Mage_Customer_AccountController::_loginPostRedirect()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php#L183).

Comment: I have put the following code, just before redirecting the customer when not logged in, but magento keeps redirecting to the user account panel. Don't hesitate to provide codes snippet, as I'm quite new in magento.          Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*'));

Answer (score 0):

and trying to put it in the controller file 'app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php' in the function "loginPostAction" just before "if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {"

Comment: Nope, it's not redirecting...